# Add variables to a form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using a Symfony 2 in a project, and I need to have dependent selects in my form. Currently I'm following this tutorial [showmethecode.es](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/) and its working.

But I'm also using options groups in the selects, and I really need to add some extra variables and some logic in the client side.

My question is, how can I add variables to a form (in the client side), and join them in a Type class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you read up on Custom Form Field types and Data transformers:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Or you create the form yourself and get the data from the request in the send action. 
You should however create a CSRF Token when creating the form and check it when submitting the form:

```
$this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
//Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider
$token = $csrf->getToken("bundlenamespace_formname");
```

And validate it like so:

```
$this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid($request->get('_token', ''));
```

Comment: Thanks that helps, I'm going to read more about that. For now, I'm just passing the variables I need, by serialize them in json format.